# What is the problem in my code? Can any please help me out

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,TextInput ,View, Text, Button, FlatList} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [Color, setState] = useState([]);
  const randomRgb = () => {
    const red =(255);
    const green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256*0);
    const blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256*0);
    return `rgb(${red},${green},${blue})`;
  };
  return (
    <View>
    <Text>Enter Any number between 1 to 19999 </Text>
    <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={(newValue)=>{
        setState(newValue);
    }}
    />
    

      <FlatList
        data={Color}
        KeyExtractor={Color => Color.item}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
    return ( <View style={{ width: 150, height: 150,backgroundColor: randomRgb(item),}}></View>);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    margin: 20,
    borderColor: '#FF0000',
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
});
export default App;
```

**My program should work in such a way that whatever number i type in text field it should create that number of boxes of red color. The current code work in this way that when i type a number it only create a single box of red color. What is the problem**

Answer (score 0):

You should update the state in a way that you are creating an array of size equal to the input number

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    onChangeText={(newValue)=>{
        setState(new Array(newValue));
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is always of size 1 since you are doing `setState(newValue);`
Instead set the state to an array of required size `setState(new Array(newValue));`

Comment: i did but same result